# Get date of last Compact on the NotesDatabase

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript

Need to programaticaly get dates of last compactation of the databases on Domino server. Either with LotusScript or Notes Formula. Any idea?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I can't think of a way to do this.  Closest feature I can think of is the `PercentUsed` property in `NotesDatabase`.  If percent used is high, the database doesn't need to be compacted.  More on `PercentUsed` here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_PERCENTUSED_PROPERTY.html

Comment: Maybe you can search the logs database (log.nsf) and try to parse the records.

Comment: I searched for the same thing a couple of months ago, but did not find a way to get the last compact date. Didn't find anything using C API function calls either.
In our case, we check the databases regularly and assume the database was compacted if the size decreased a lot. A clumsy solution, but it helps for us.